# how to manage dates in shell

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, date

emphasized textI have a file containing 14000 dates . I wrote a script to find the last 5 days ,

```
26/03/2002:11:52:25
27/03/2002:11:52:25
29/03/2002:11:30:41
30/03/2002:11:30:41
26/03/2002:11:30:41
02/04/2002:11:30:41
03/04/2002:11:30:41
04/04/2002:11:30:41
05/04/2002:11:52:25
06/04/2002:11:52:25
```

suppose this is the file , now I have date 02/04/2002:11:30:41 as an out put . I want to put the dates from 02/04/2002 till the end of the file in another file .

```
start-date = 02/04/2002 (this is my start date) 
while [start-date lt end-date] do (while start date is less than end date )
start-date++ ( add one day to start day so if its 2/4/2002 it will become 3/4/2002)
echo $start-date|tee -a file1  (put it in a file)
```

Comment: Stackoverflow would probably be the more appropriate forum for this, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Is it sorted in ascending order? I see the `26/03/2002:11:30:41` at the middle.

Comment: yes the file is sorted ascending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to do this: grep, sed, awk, ...

You can get the line number of matching pattern by one of the following:

- `grep -n pattern -m 1 input | cut -d: -f1`
- `awk '/pattern/{ print NR }' input | head -1`

and print from that line to the end of the file:

- `$ sed -n "$(awk '/02\/04\/2002:11:30:41/ { print NR }' input | head -1),$ p"
  input`

or:

- `$ awk 'NR >= line_number' line_number=$(grep -n 02/04/2002:11:30:41
  -m 1 input | cut -d: -f1) input`

You also can use `grep -A` (`--after-context`) or `tail`, ...

Comment: I did not get what you wrote , my matching pattern is a date which is in $SDATE and my input file which should be checked is a logfile; I check this code but it was not right, it suppose to print the last 5 days and the start date is located in $SDATE

Comment: i check it , it was wrong ! :(                                       grep -n $SDATE aa.log | cut -d: -f1
sed '/$SDATE/=' aa.log
awk '/$SDATE/{ print NR }' aa.log
$ sed -n "$(awk '/02\/04\/2002:11:30:41/ { print NR }' aa.log),$ p" aa.log
$ awk 'NR >= line_number' line_number=$(grep -n 02/04/2002:11:30:41 -m 1 aa.log | cut -d: -f1) aa.log

Comment: You don't understand what you're doing. Use one of the aboves, not all.

Comment: I wrote sed -n "$(awk '/01\/04\/2002:11:30:41/ { print NR }' thttpd.log),$ p" thttpd.log as you said but again it has problem !           

sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `,'

Comment: The reason is you have multiples line including **01/04/2002:11:30:41**, so the best way is use `grep -n 02/04/2002:11:30:41 -m 1` to print only the first maching.

Comment: I could not run this command ! while i run it i face with error command not found !  awk 'NR >= line_number' line_number=$(grep -n 30/Dec/2002:22:01:25 -m 1 thttpd.log | cut -d: -f1) thttpd.log

Answer (score 1):

If you can do with an external helper tool, try [dateutils](http://hroptatyr.github.com/dateutils/).  It comes with a `dgrep` command which does what you want:

```
dgrep '>=2002-04-02' -i '%d/%m/%Y' < yourfile
=>
  02/04/2002:11:30:41
  03/04/2002:11:30:41
  04/04/2002:11:30:41
  05/04/2002:11:52:25
  06/04/2002:11:52:25
```